# How to automatically purge old data in GridDB

Tags: griddb

I am using GridDB to store time-series data from various sensors. The data accumulates over time and I am looking for a way to automatically purge old data to manage storage and keep the database optimized.

I went through the documentation, but I did not find any feature or method for automatic data purging based on timestamps or data age.

Question,
Is there a built-in feature in GridDB to set up automatic purging of old data?
If not, what would be the best approach to implement automatic purging mechanism, especially for time-series data? Are there any recommended external tools out there or scripts that can be used to automate data purging in GridDB?